# How to create form in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

There is block HTML with article:

```
<div class="block">
   <span ng-click="edit()">Click</span>
   <div class="title">How to</div>
   <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>
```

When I call edit function `ng-click="edit()"` I call AJAX that returns data:

```
title
text
```

These data I set in `$scope`:

```
$scope.title = title;
$scope.text = text;
```

How I can create form with input, textarea instead HTML in `.block`?
I neeed to switch on edit mode and display form for editing.

Comment: can you do a jsfiddle?

Comment: This is all what I have, I need to create HTML form on place instead title, text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially asking how to do a form.  I would try going through some examples from the documentation eg.     https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form

paying key attention to the ng-model="" tags to bind your data fields.  Then the scope variables should automatically update your form.